# Get CatalogInventory stock collection in Observer

Tags: magento2, collection, inventory, cataloginventory

I need, on website save, get the inventory with the current website ID.

Ad I'm trying to get the CatalogInventory Stock Collection in an Observer, but it finish with the error:

```
Configuration array must have a key for 'dbname' that names the database instance
```

My Code is:

```
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $stockCollection = $objectManager->create('\Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\ResourceModel\Stock\Collection');
}
```

The event is: website_save_after

What is wrong with this?

I used this example:
[Magento 2 Get product collection](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/92278/magento-2-get-product-collection)

Comment: For which event you try?

Comment: <event name="website_save_after">

Comment: What is your exactly need? You try to pick wrong collection.

Comment: I need, on website save, get the inventory with the current website ID

Comment: What exactly do you mean by inventory? In your code you're trying to load a collection of "Stock" objects. Is that what you are referring to as inventory here?

Comment: I would suggest using the StockRepository class to get the collection you desire or even better use interfaces e.g. StockRepositoryInterface.  I can provide a working example, using interfaces, of what you're trying to accomplish if you want.  I didn't provide it as an answer as it doesn't answer your specific question.